# executing code too fast..need to slow down but how?

Tags: java

from this code below

```
  if(!validate_containsNum && !validate_isNumber && !validate_isBlankField){
                a.sendMsgToSlave("DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs:"+pName_sub);
                appendToGlobalDataLog("SEND : DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs:"+pID+":"+p_sub);
                String pID = pID_Manage.getText();  
                a.addtoArrayList("DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs:"+pID+":"+pName_sub);
                at.sendToServer("DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs:"+pID+":"+pName_sub);



        }
```

from the code above i am having a problem where this line

```
      a.sendMsgToSlave("DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs:"+pName_sub);
```

is actually calling my client to  fetch data from peoples TABLE in order to get pID in return which will be return to a JTEXTFIELD where the next line should be executed

```
     String pID = pID_Manage.getText();
```

but then as for the next line job is to add certain String into an arraylist which has the combination of pID and pName_Sub but then when executed it i found out my arraylist did not have the pID..so instead of the real result should be something like this

```
     DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs:1:ALBERT  (In my arraylist)
```

it shows like this

```
     DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs::ALBERT (the id is missing)
```

i need to resubmit again the 2nd time only can get the ID...it seems like the execution of the code is too fast and the storing of ID in return to the JTEXTFIELD is slow..any way to slow it down?

Comment: This isn't a case of code executing too quickly, this is a race condition.  The correct solution is for `a.sendMsgToSlave()` either to block until the slave's PID has been calculated and stored, or for `a.sendMsgToSlave()` to return the PID.  Actually, the best solution is both of those together.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution is to call `Thread.Sleep`, but the better solution is to modify the code in `a.sendMsgToSlave()` to return only after the id is set.  That way you know for sure that when the execution gets to the statement after `sendMsgToSlave()` you will definitely have the ID ready every time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sendMsgToSlave` starts an asynchronous chain of events that results in the text field being updated at some later point. You should modify your architecture so that the code that depends on the ID field being set runs in reaction to that event actually happening. As others have mentioned, you can make `sendMsgToSlave` synchronous, but judging from its name, I don't think that's a really good idea. What you could do is attach a *change listener* to the ID field that will do the rest of the task. I'll approximate as I don't know the exact listener you're going to need:

```
pID_Manager.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() { 
  public void textChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    pID_manager.removeChangeListener(this);
    String pID = pID_Manage.getText();  
    a.addtoArrayList("DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs:"+pID+":"+pName_sub);
    at.sendToServer("DATA:TAKE:PEOPLEs:"+pID+":"+pName_sub);
}};
```

So the basic idea is that the listener reacts to the appropriate event and that it immediately deregisters itself upon firing.

Comment: hmm i am new to this changelistener..i seem to be unable to add my jtextfield into it...i am using eclipse when i type my pID_Manage.addChange i see nth related to it..

Comment: As I said, I'm approximating the code, sorry about this. After a glance at `JTextField` I wasn't immediately sure which listener to use. Could be the `VetoableChangeListener`, but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 0):

the following is your sollution:
put changelistener on the jtextfield pID_Manage
and call your array populating method in it
so that the array will only be populated when the id is recieved and assigned to the jtextfield.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but with things like trying to prevent rainbow tables in hashes and other security problems, doing something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
}
```

might do the trick. But again I've never tested this, it's just a suggestion

Comment: How do rainbow tables relate to fixing a race condition?

Comment: Sorry, I was kind of thinking about slowing it down by adding pointless things, I've seen php scripts do this so trying to generate rainbow tables take up to 1000 times longer because it has to do the loop 1000 times

Comment: @Luke But real hackers will just remove the time-wasting portions of the code before using it, anyway.  Please read http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm, for the _correct_ way to  deal with security issues like that.